# Multi level headers in Pandas - Header for Index

Tags: python

I have an excel file which looks like that

```
   Column 1              Column 2    Column 3
   Header 1                     Header 2  
   Header 1 merged       Header 2.1  Header 2.2

    data                   data        data
```

Header 2 is merged between column 2 and 3,
Header 1 is merged between row 1 and row 2

When I read that in pandas I get header 1 with the corresponding data below as an index. However I cannot access header 1 nor change it. Any ideas why is this happening? Note that when I reset the index, Header 1 stays as a header for the reset index and still cannot access it.

What I get from pandas is this:

```
df = pd.read_excel("excel.xlsx", header=[0, 1])
```

`header 1  header 2     header 2
           header 2.1   header 2.2
 data      data         data`

First column is read as the index, which is fine. However I cannot get access of header 1 nor remove it.

Thanks